# How to mock an object, declared / initialized inside a method under test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit, moq

Consider this programs

```
public class ItemManager
{
    private ItemFetcher itemFetcher;
    public ItemManager(ItemFetcher _itemFetcher)
    {
        itemFetcher = _itemFetcher;
    }
    public List<Item> GetItemsFomTable()
    {
        List<Item> itemsList = new List<Item>();
        Item item;

        DataTable resultDataTable = itemFetcher.GetItemsFromDB();

        foreach (DataRow row in resultDataTable.Rows)
        {
            item = new Item();
            // set item's name property
            // set item's price property
            itemsList.Add(item);
        }
        return itemsList; 
    }
}
public class Item
{
    string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    double price;

    public double Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }
}
public class ItemFetcher
{
    public virtual DataTable GetItemsFromDB()
    {
        // DoSomething and fetch records in DataTable and return
        return new DataTable();
    }
}
```

I want to test itemFetcher.GetItemsFromDB method is called once in the method "GetItemsFomTable()" of the class ItemManager. Here is the Test

```
[TestFixture]
    public class ItemManagerTester
    {        
        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {

        }
        [Test]
        public void TestForGetItemsFomTable()
        {
            var mockItemFetcher = new Mock<ItemFetcher>();
            var itemManager = new ItemManager(mockItemFetcher.Object);

            mockItemFetcher.Setup(x => x.GetItemsFromDB());
            itemManager.GetItemsFomTable();

            mockItemFetcher.VerifyAll();
        }
    }
```

As you may see there is List initialised inside the method under test

```
List<Item> itemsList = new List<Item>();
```

I get this Exception raised:

```
TestCase 'MockingSample.ItemManagerTester.TestForGetItemsFomTable'
failed: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    ItemManager.cs(26,0): at MockingSample.ItemManager.GetItemsFomTable()
    ItemManager.cs(77,0): at MockingSample.ItemManagerTester.TestForGetItemsFomTable()
```

What should I do with the List ? How and where can I mock this if needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't specified a return value, the mock item fetcher returns null, so the attempt to access `resultDataTable.Rows` throws.

To fix the error, tell Moq what you want it to return when you configure the expectation:

```
mockItemFetcher.Setup(x => x.GetItemsFromDB()).Returns(new DataTable());
```